# Sorted sequence algorithm of disctinct integers

Tags: sequences-and-series, algorithms

[image]

I have been been given this task and need some help with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:  $\log n$ should make you think of binary search.  Note that the $a_i$ increase at least as fast as $i$ because they are sorted distinct integers.